# Accessing .sqlite file in Android 2.1

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a .sqlite file with one table in it. i want to access this data. Please tell me, where to copy this .sqlite file (in eclipse project) and how to access the data from this .sqlite file.

please suggest some code or liniks.. [i am using Android 2.1, dont know the database version..]

Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few articles that explain exactly that ;)

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-have-default-database

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

[Include a database file with Android application via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991667/include-a-database-file-with-android-application-via-eclipse)